# What is "serial concatenation"?

Tags: aes, keys, key-exchange, rijndael

I have a third-party point-of-sale API (Speedflow Pay-N-Get) that I am trying to communicate with over HTTP, but I have a problem with it.

In a nutshell, a request is encrypted using RSA, and the response is encrypted using RSA followed by Rijndael/AES-128.  The RSA keys are provided by the vendor, the AES IV is a vendor-provided guid, and the AES key is the vendor-provided guid and a random requester-generated guid combined using "serial concatenation".  The random guid is included as a parameter of the request.

I am using OpenSSL to handle the encryption/decryption.

I have everything working except the AES portion.  I have no clue what "serial concatenation" is, online searches do not find any useful info about it, and the vendor has not replied yet.  Does anyone know what this is?

**Update:** Here is what the API doc says about the AES portion of the encryption:

> The server response — EDATA data in the body of the HTTP response.
>
> Formula: EDATA = Base64(Rj(RSA1(DATA)))
>
> Rj — symmetric algorithm Rijandel-128
>
> IV — Guid # 1 value, converted to a byte array
>
> Key — value Guid # 1 and Guid # 2 (serial concatenation)
>
> mode spacing — Zeroes

Also:

> -----Decryption.-----
>
> RSA (AES ( BASE64( response ) ) ),
>
> where RSA - RSA- private-key encryption
>
> AES - Symmetric key encryption
>
> response – server response
>
> -----AES-----
>
> use bouncyCastle: cipher= PaddedBufferedBlockCipher ( CBCBlockCipher ( RijndaelEngine(128)),
>   ZeroBytePadding() );
>
> cipher.init (false, ParametersWithIV ( KeyParameter ( mykey ), iv )
>   );
>
> where mykey- coding in hex string guid3
>
> iv- concatenation coding in hex string guid3 and coding in hex string guid2
>
> Encoding is performed on this algorithm by taking two character of a string is converted to hex and added to an array of bytes.

Guid#1 is the vendor-provided Guid, Guid#2 is the randomly generated Guid.  Both are included in a request.  I suspect the second paragraph actually meant the IV is Guid3 and the key is the concatenation of Guid3 and Guid2.  Guid3 is just Guid1 with its first 3 fields converted to big endian.

Since an AES-128 key is only 16 bytes in size, and a Guid is also 16 bytes in size, I suspect that "serial concatenation" would be somehow hashing them together, rather then simply appending them to each other, which would produce a 32-byte key instead.

Comment: Serial concatenation sounds a lot like concatenation to me. Expressed in PHP code (because it has the easiest concatenation opearators), `$var= $a . $b`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming issues and not cryptography.

Comment: @rath: i tried that kind of simple concatenation before and it did not work. I'm not asking for programming help, I'm asking for help understanding a cryptography concept I have never heard of before. I have seen references to ”serial concatenation” and ”parallel concatenation” in my searches but do not know what they actually are, let alone how to implement them in code.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a crypto concept, but I may be wrong. Would you mind adding a link to the relevant API page?

Comment: @rath: the API is for a private service and the tech document I have was given to me by a client I am writting the software for and has the client's personal info in it. I will copy the relevant portions tomorrow, but they are very minimal in detail.

Comment: @rath: I added some info from the API spec.

Comment: Giving you a constructive heads-up: [check these related books and references](https://www.google.com/search?&hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22Serial+concatenation%22+cryptography). The term “serial concatenation” only borders crypto, as it's actually a term used in relation to signal processing... which frequently means “serial concatenation” is mentioned in one sentence with related cryptographic implementations, but it's not a crypto-term in itself (think *SigInt*). I'm sure the link I provided will give you a usable starting point if you want to learn more about what "serial concatenation" exactly is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Serial concatenation" is not a standard term in cryptography.  Without any further information, I would guess that it probably refers to just concatenation.  If that's not what it refers to, then your spec is deficient and ambiguous; you'll need to consult with the author of the spec to ask for to clarify what they meant by that phrase.